# Keep longest strings while removing those partially matched with them

Tags: autohotkey

I have a set of data like this:

```
I love
Hong Kong
I love Hong Kong and Japan.
and Japan.
test.
just a
This is just a test.
```

I would like to keep the longest ones while removing those partially matched with them. the desired result:

```
I love Hong Kong and Japan. 
This is just a test.
```

but the actual result is

```
I love
I love Hong Kong and Japan.
This is just a test.
```

Here are my code in AHK:

```
FileEncoding, UTF-8

FileSelectFile, FileName

FileRead, Var, %FileName%

lines_master := StrSplit(Var, "`r`n") 

l :=lines_master.MaxIndex() 

lines_temp :=[]

Remaining_List =

count_match = 0

While l > 1
{
    for i, element in lines_master
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            master :=element
        }
        Else
        {
            if !InStr(master, element)
            {
                lines_temp.Insert(element)
                count_match := count_match + 1
            }
        }
    }
    x := l - 1
    if (count_match == x)
    {
        lines_temp.Insert(master)
    }
    else
    {
        Remaining_List .=master . "`r`n" 
    }
    count_match = 0
    lines_master :=lines_temp
    lines_temp :=[]
    l :=lines_master.MaxIndex()

}

FileAppend, %Remaining_List%, F:\result.txt, UTF-8


Exit
```

if I sort the list by length in words, it works. However, I would like to know how to refine the code and make it work no matter what order the list of strings is in.

thank you.

Comment: The script actually works. the problem is caused as there is any empty trailing line in my sample file.  just added a few lines to remove any empty lines.

Comment: anyway, this one is inefficient to process large batches of data. any better suggestions are welcome. thank you.